# Increase the distance in the TextDecoration line - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text, distance, underline

Is there a property in the Text widget to increase the distance between the text and the underline from TextDecoration property?

Example:

```
Text('Example',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize:15 ,decoration: TextDecoration.underline,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in solution but there's a walk around for this.
You need to create a shadow of text and change its color. It's visible.
The original text color must be transparent.
And then use as many space as you want using Offset property.

```
Text('Text and underline space',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              decorationColor: Colors.grey,
              /// change -20 to as many space as you need but it must be less than 0
              shadows: [Shadow(color: Colors.white, offset: Offset(0, -20))],
              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
              decorationThickness: 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to make a text shadow and change its color.

```
 Text('Approve',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.merge(TextStyle(
                            shadows: [
                              Shadow(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  offset: Offset(0, -5))
                            ],
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            decoration:
                            TextDecoration.underline,
                            decorationColor: Colors.green,
                            decorationThickness: 2,
                            //decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.dashed,
                          ),
                          )
```